# How I can wrapper printf c++ function in Python

Tags: python, c++, printf, wrapper, variadic-functions

I'd wrapper a printf `c++` function in **Python** . I pass the format string in PyArg_ParseTuple with s and lStringFormat. But how can I pass the other value? I don't know them before receiving .

For example i would write

```
int years = 30
printfPy("I am %d old", years)
```

wrapper look like this....

```
static PyObject* PrintfPy(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    char* lStringFormat;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s...", &lStringFormat, ...))
        return NULL;

    sprintf(lStringFormat, ...);

}
```

any suggestion for me?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to portably convert an array, a list, a PyObject storing a tuple, or any other normal data structure into an variable-length argument list suitable for `printf` or `vprintf` or any similar function. In particular it is not possible to turn a non-variable-arguments function like printfPy into a generic wrapper to a variable-arguments function. In order to make a call to a `printf`-like function with dynamically determined number of arguments of dynamically determined types, a function must either have `...` in its argument list, or somehow get a hold of an object of type `va_list`, which in turn can only be constructed from a `...` in an argument list of some function. (It is not possible to call `printf` itself this way at all. One can only call one of the `v...` family of functions though, such as `vprintf`, but one still must start from a `...` in some function argument list.)

A reasonably (but not universally) portable solution would involve a third-party library like libffi. It probably will not be easy for a beginner.

Since the question is labelled C++: there are ways to avoid C-style variable-length function argument lists in C++ almost completely, except when such functions come in third-party libraries you need to support. Use C++ alternatives to printf and friends, and write your own functions to accept standard containers instead of variable-length argument lists.